# Electroweak Unification: Relation between $g_{W}$ and $g_{Z}$

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, electroweak

In his book "Modern Particle Physics", Mark Thomson states that $$g_{Z} = \frac{g_{W}}{\cos\theta_{W}},$$ cf. Page 484 Figure 17.12. Unfortunately, I don't really get where this comes from. What I know are the following relations:

$$e = g_{W}\sin\theta_{W} = g'\cos\theta_{W}, \quad m_{W} = \cos\theta_{W}\cdot m_{Z}, \quad g_{Z} = g\cos\theta_{W}I_{3}-g'\sin\theta_{W}\frac{Y}{2},$$

but I still don't see how to arrive at the desired Eq.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text sensibly assumes you have internalized the lesson of the previous page, p 483.

For the *W*s, couplings to the Higgs trail masses faithfully, scaled by a factor of 2,
$$
\frac{ g^2}{4} W^- W^+ (v+h)^2 = \frac{ g^2 v^2}{4} W^- W^+ +    \frac{ g^2 v}{2} W^- W^+ h + O(h^2)\\
=m_W^2  W^- W^+ + g_W m_W W^- W^+ h + O(h^2),
$$
where I have supplanted $g_W=g$, as he does, since the Ws  only couple via the SU(2) charges *g*, and, of course, $m_W= g_W v/2$.

Now you may recall the mixing of the *B* with $W^3$, and you proceed identically as here in the diagonalization: everywhere you had a $v^2$ in the $Z^0$ mass term, you also have a $g_Z m_Z ZZh$ coupling trailing the $m_Z^2 ZZ $ mass term!
$$
\frac{ g_Z ^2}{4}  Z^2 (v+h)^2\equiv \frac{ 1}{4}  (-g'B+gW^3)^2 (v+h)^2\\
= \frac{g^2+g' ^2 }{4}  (-\sin\theta_w B+\cos \theta_w W^3)^2 (v+h)^2,
$$
with $g_Z^2= g^2+ g'^2=g_W^2/\cos^2\theta_w.$

You [*know*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle) $m_Z= m_W/\cos\theta_w$, so, of course, the Higgs couplings follow suit,
$$
\frac{m_W}{m_Z} = \frac{g_W}{g_Z} = \cos\theta_w .
$$
This is merely a reference to the mass generation section.

As a bonus, you may reassure yourself the (neutral) Higgs does not couple to the photon... for the very same reason the photon lacks a mass term!

Comment: "of course, the Higgs couplings follow suit" --> No, this is not clear to me yet. Why is that the case? Yes, we know that $g_{HWW}$ - the coupling strength at the $HWW$ vertex is $g_{W}m_{W}$ and $g_{HZZ} = g_{Z}m_{Z}$. And yes, we can also re-write $g_{HZZ} = g_{Z}\frac{m_{W}}{\cos\theta_{W}}$, and what can we do then?

Comment: The crucial part is you also saw $m_Z/g_Z= v/2= m_W/g_W$ by comparing with its adjacent mass term!

Comment: Oh, that's good to know!